# How to do phonetic search in DSE Graph qremlin query?

Tags: gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I've gone through the possibilities of `phrase`, `tokenFuzzy`, `fuzzy` search options presented in [DSE Graph Documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/useSearchIndexes.html). But these would not be sufficient to search for the case say `Anish` and `Aneesh` both spelled differently but pronounced more or less similarly.

Is there a way to use the underlying [Solar phonetic search](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Phonetic+Matching) capabilities in gremlin queries?

Similar pairs of words are `Muller` and `Mueller`!

Answer (score 1):

Because of the integration with DSE Graph and DSE Search, there is no special Gremlin syntax to achieve this.  To accomplish this in DSE Graph you would change the SOLR Core for the Vertex Label to add the desired filter to the analyzer chain.  Something like the following could be used:

```
ALTER SEARCH INDEX SCHEMA ON graph_name.vertex_label_p
ADD types.fieldType [ @name='phonetic' , @class='org.apache.solr.schema.TextField' ]
  WITH 
    $${
        "analyzer": [
          {
            "filter": [
              { "class": "solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" },
              { 
                "class": "solr.BeiderMorseFilterFactory", 
                "nameType": "GENERIC", 
                "ruleType": "APPROX",
                "concat": "true",
                "languageSet": "auto" 
              }
            ],
            "tokenizer": { "class": "solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" }
          }
        ]
      }$$;
```

...and then to make those changes active...

```
RELOAD SEARCH INDEX ON graph_name.vertex_label_p;
```

We have had other users use BMPM with DSE Search but I'm not aware of anyone using it with Graph to date.

With any SOLR extension added to the analyzer, you may see some increase in hardware utilization, CPU in particular.

Comment: Thank you very much @jlacefie for the answer. This doesn't seem to be straight forward, considering my naivety in Solr, I'll attempt it in coming weeks once I feel comfortable fiddling with the internals. One quick question though, after doing this, will the index be automatically picked up? or should I query the solr separately before firing my gremlin query?

Comment: The index should be used if you are using the has statement for the property.  There should not be a need to execute a SOLR query directly.

Comment: I've changed the first two lines to `ALTER SEARCH INDEX SCHEMA ON MyGraph.Person_p_search
ADD types.fieldType [ @name='callingName' , @class='org.apache.solr.schema.TextField' ]` but it doesn't compile. I couldn't figure out which keyspace to run this CQL command on! I've tried on all the keyspaces in MyGraph Notebook in the DSE Studio. But no luck. I've created my search index using `schema.vertexLabel('Person').index('search').search().by('callingName').asText().add()`